# What are the valid values in abstract xsd element

Tags: xml, xsd

In our project I found this piece of xsd. I am really confused what are the valid values in element AbstractItems

XSD:

```
<xs:element name="ListOfItems">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="AbstractItems" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="AbstractItems" abstract="true"/>
```

generated xml agains wsdl looks like:

```
<urn1:ListOfItems>
   <!--Optional:-->
   <urn1:Abstractitems>?</urn1:Abstractitems>
</urn1:ListOfItems>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From W3School[1](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp%20W3schools)

Abstract: Specifies whether the element can be used in an instance document. True indicates that the element cannot appear in the instance document. Instead, another element whose substitutionGroup attribute contains the qualified name (QName) of this element must appear in this element's place. Default is false